# Projection of c onto the plane OAB

Tags: vectors

I am having issues with a question set about vector projection. I have three position vectors, a, b and c. They are:
$$a= - i + j - k$$ 
$$b= - 2i + j - 3k$$
$$c= - i + 2j$$

I am asked to find the projection of c on the plane spanned by a and b. However, when I come to "dot" my normal vector (normal to plane) with c, I get zero-is there any other way of finding the projection?

My normal vector (found from crossing a with b) is:
$$n= - 2i - j + k$$
Dotting this with my c vector gives zero?

Comment: That would mean c already does lie in the plane spanned by a and b since it's orthogonal to the normal of the plane

Answer (score 0):

Just write $c=\alpha a+\beta b+\gamma n$ and calculate $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

$\alpha a+\beta b$ would be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since dot product of $c$ with the **normal** to the plane is $0$, it lies *in* the plane defined by $a$ and $b$.

I.e. it is coplanar to $a$ and $b$.

Therefore it's projection in the plane is $c$ itself.

Or formally speaking, since $a,b$ and $c$ are coplanar $ \implies ~\exists~ \alpha ,\beta $ such that $c=\alpha a+\beta b$. *(Or as stated by @Michael in his answer, $\gamma$ would be $0$)*